# Laravel Query Builder join on json data column

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

On my database, I have a notifications table that has a data column containing a JSON string like this one:

```
{"sender_id":2,"sender_name":"John Doe","message":"Hello world!"}
```

What I need is to join the users table on users.id = notifications.data.sender_id but I don't know how or if it's even possible. Couldn't find any info regarding this kind of query.

Looking forward to reading your solutions. Thanks!

Comment: `json_decode($string, true);` to decode it but for querying it, I don't think there is a possible way. Why don't you store them as separate columns?

Comment: i am working on an existing project with a lot of db records. changing the db structure isn't an option..

Comment: Is it only these 3 keys? If so, I'd honestly change the db structure, otherwise you'd need to query with %like% which is a lot slower

Comment: most of the times yes, but there are cases when there are 2 more extra keys...

Comment: Let's hear what other will say. If not, it's not that difficult to change the database at all, you just need a seeder to seed the data in the right format in your db :) The current structure will keep biting you in the future I suspect - or at least add 1 new column to your table for `sender_id` and leave the json column as it is, will solve your problem

Comment: Yeah, I might end up doing just that. Thanks for your time and suggestions. I am really curious if it's even possible...

Comment: hmm join tables with where clause then decode json and if condition, i'm gonna need a code what you've tried so far, seems like possible to me...i know it's high and bumpy road but only if that's what you wanted otherwise @senty is right change you're DB columns to make it easier to fetch

Comment: Are you using MySQL? If so, what version are you using?

Comment: What does the whole query look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a little hacky solution which is this:

```
$id = 123;
YourModel::where('json_data_column', 'like', '%"sender_id":' . $id . ',%');
```

You are basically doing a string search in the JSON. However, there is also a `JSON` column type in MySQL, which allows better support for JSON searches. You can then do:

```
$id = 123;
YourModel::where('json_data_column->sender_id', $id);
```